# React Native function to render Element dynamically doesn't render anything

Tags: react-native

I wrote a function to render views dynamically based on an object. But the function does not render any views when invoked.

I've tried adding and taking away render() in my function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
        var arr = this.state.response;
        Object.keys(arr).map(key => {
            console.log(arr[key]);
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{key}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        })
    }
```

And the renderRow function is called in the view like this

```
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
                        <Text>Name</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
                        <Text>Sales</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
                        <Text>Commission</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
                        <Text>Payout</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
                        <Text>Profit</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                {this.renderRow()}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: `return Object.keys...`

Comment: This works! I see what I did wrong, not only I have to return the elements, I have to return the array iteration in the function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `renderRow` function

```
renderRow = () => {
   const arr = this.state.response;
   return Object.keys(arr).map(key => 
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{key}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
                        <Text>{arr[key].sales}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
}
```

Comment: What's the reason behind why you would change the var to const?

Comment: it's a new definition but it no really matter...so you can ignore it for this example.
Does the answer to help you?

Comment: yup it did, adding the return in front of Object solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: @benjaminwong Great!, so if it solved your question please upvote my answer and mark as a solution

Comment: You got it! @idan

Answer (score 0):

Your `renderRow` function does not return anything...

`return  Object.keys(arr).map(key => {`

Comment: Got it, it's working now. Thank you for your guidance!